# Видео на полный экран с youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

Я вставляю на сайт YouTube видео через `iframe`. Можно ли при нажатии на **play** открывать видео в полный экран?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать повесить `callback onStateChange` на [API YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru#Events)

в функции отследить состояния воспроизведения `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` и если состояние было не активное и стало активное значит запустили видео, дальше можно открыть его на весь экран с помощью html5 fullscreen api пример кода на [codepen](https://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/GgOvLM)

Comment: Возможно так будет работать, но мне нужно именно когда видео вставлено через iframe

Comment: с iframe не получится сделать, потому что js не имеет доступ к iframe это сделано специально браузерами для безопасности.